# What should be the relay state value for SP initiated SAML in Okta?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, okta

I am setting up a SP initiated SAML 2.0 app using Okta and i am not sure about what the relay state value and audience URI should be.

My SP URL - `https://sampleapp.company.com/appname/default.aspx`

My SAML ACS URL - `https://sampleapp.company.com/appname/SAML/authenticate.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

The RelayState value is an **optional** hint for a SAML SP.

The RelayState is an *unauthenticated* and *unverified* value that is passed from a SAML IDP to a SAML SP. You can put whatever you want into the RelayState, but it's typically understood to be the URL of where you'd like to user to be redirected to after a successful SAML authentication.